# Unauthorized error while using jQuery AJAX for Auth Token

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on authentication using auth token, everything is fine and I have auth Token which I have stored using sessionStorage and carrying the same to headers, but it always shows below error

```
GET http://someurl.com/services/api/ts?call…y214052125942427665_1438618929218&q=&sort=&sd=&skip=&take=&_=1438618929219 401 (Unauthorized)
```

jQuery Code

```
getAllData = function () {
    var qData = { q: '', sort: '', sd: '', skip: '', take: '' };
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://someurl.com/services/api/ts', // dummy url
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': "bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem('authToken')
        },
        data: qData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like the authToken is invalid, has expired, or your server is not configured for header auth tokens.

Comment: How to add authToken to the request headers? I am using swagger and there I can see "Authorization: bearer afdasfd..." in request headers but at my local I can't see the same?